# how to increase number of file more than 20 as i have changed settings in php.ini?

Tags: php, upload, wamp

In php.ini i have changed the values

```
post_max_size = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
```

but still im not able to upload more than 20 files.
i am using wamp 2.1
Help Me Please

Comment: Could you add your code and the size of the 20 files ? You need to change max_file_uploads. Oh and tell us the error you receive :)

Answer (score 0):

```
max_file_uploads = 1000 // Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
```

Add this to your php.ini in `[PHP]` section

```
post_max_size = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_file_uploads = 1000
```

Comment: also changing php.ini requires webserver restart